# Pandas split csv into multiple csv by unique ID

Tags: python, pandas

I am really lost and need some helps or tips

I have a CSV file with duplicates IDs and I want to split it into multiple CSV containing one unique id per CSV file

expected output should be

file1.csv

```
 person_name     id    Total  Paid        Date          No
      Deniss  55227  1191,75  0,00  21/08/2019  15/06/2018
      RINALDS  56002   169,00  0,00  21/08/2019  15/06/2018
      OLGA  54689   812,90  0,00  21/08/2019  15/05/2018
```

file2.csv

```
 person_name     id    Total  Paid        Date          No
      Deniss  55227  1191,75  0,00  21/08/2019    20180615
     RINALDS  56002   169,00  0,00  21/08/2019    20180615
        OLGA  54689   812,90  0,00  21/08/2019    20180515
```

Comment: Would you mind also adding the expected output?

Comment: I have done that

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: You haven't split the data by unique id, you split based on the format of the date in the `No` column.  In any case the `df.No = pd.to_datetime(df.No)` and then `df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)` because the data you're showing is all the same, aside from the format of the `No` string.

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
[df.loc[df['id']==x].to_csv() for x in df['id'].unique()]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
file_2 = data[data.duplicated(subset='id')]
file_1 = data[~data['No'].isin(list(typee_1['No']))]
```

You can use this to get your desired result

Comment: Worked but what if there are 4 occurrences of the ids it means this wouldnt work

Comment: Choose your subset based on the requirement. hCange it according to the duplication. If you can select duplicates by making subset of id and date, then use that. Other part will remain the same.